# How to Fix/Rehabilitate Soft Plastic Retaining Clip

Tags: clips

Having a small problem trying to state this clearly...anyhoo:

When replacing cabin air filter for my car (2007 Toyota 4-Runner), it is necessary to get behind the glove box (or whatever it is called now) which requires removing a piston/strut thingy on the passenger side of box.  The YT video linked here starts at about the right place to make this clearer:

https://youtu.be/NjfycJTJG7M?si=qG___HDObfcaBxJP

But the "mechanic" that did this 1st time a while back didn't understand and just pushed the box down until the soft plastic retaining clip that holds the piston/strut thingy at top gave way and seems to have permanently deformed. (see pic attached.)  It has never really worked to retain that thingy since I've owned the vehicle (purchased used) such that the glove box occasionally falls out farther than it should when the piston thingy drops off the retaining clip.  And since that retaining clip is an integrated part of the plastic housing around the compartment, it can't be individually replaced.

**So my question is: are there any approaches or suggestions as to how I can get this thing to work as originally intended?**  Note that space/thing are *really* hard to get at even with a couple of fingers...it's like playing Operation (tm).  For instance, I've tried to place a small folded wad of paper in between the clip prongs to hold the clip more open...I found it pretty much intractable to get at it with enough precision such that it would stay, especially when trying to get the piston thingy to hang back on it.

[image]